# Django Adding User details to a UserPost List View

Tags: python, django

I have a UserPost List View which is a view for a specific user's posts. I am looping the posts of this specific user but I want to add this user's profile details like profile image and other details like email.

So, I am not sure on how to add the user details of the user's post names as designer not the logged-in user.

I can add the user/designer details in every looped post but I don't want it to be repeated with every post I just want it to appear once just like `{{ view.kwargs.username }}` as this page is realted only to this user/designer

Here is the models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

here is the profile model related to every user

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                  'email']
```

here is the views for the userpostlist which is filtered by a specific user/designer not the logged in user

```
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "user_posts.html"
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(admin_approved=True)
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(designer=user, admin_approved=True).order_by('-date_posted')

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        has_items = Item.objects.filter(designer__username=self.kwargs['username']).exists()
        context['has_items'] = has_items
        return context
```

here is the template

```
{% if has_items %}
<h1 class="display-4">Hello, this is {{ view.kwargs.username }} </h1>
<img class="profile_image" src={{ designer.profile.image.url }}> <----------- I want it to appear
{{ designer.email }}<----------- I want it to appear
{% else %}
Show nothing
{% endif %}

{% for post in posts %}
Post details
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @ItsMilann true but it must be inside the loop i don't want it to be repeated with every post

Comment: if it is related to the designer, why don't you create a sort of detail view for user/designer and list all the user's post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to the context:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'user_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(admin_approved=True)
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            designer__username=self.kwargs['username']
        ).order_by('-date_posted')

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['designer'] = designer = get_object_or_404(
            get_user_model(),
            username=self.kwargs['username']
        )
        context['has_items'] = Item.objects.filter(designer=designer).exists()
        return context
```